# Is there a way for me to search a JSON array backwards using regex?

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

So I have a string set up like [this](http://pastebin.com/VD58px7U). That is a JSON string, storing data in this format:

```
{
    "players": {
        <playerID>: {
            "presets": [{
                "title": <title>,
                "presetId": <id>,
                "preset": {<presetData>},
                "votes": <voteCount>,
                "date": <creationDate>
            }]
        }
}
```

I want to be able to input a `presetId`, and get a `playerId` as the output (basically find out which player has the preset with that id). The same thing can be achieved by looping through each player, and each player's presets, and see if that preset has the correct id, but I need to be doing this a lot, and I feel that that would be quite costly. Would regex be better? What kind of expression would I use?

Comment: Regex would be almost certainly worse.

Comment: It's that bad? Maybe I can just loop through it all once, and store the results for the near future instead.

Comment: Sounds like you're in the browser, yes? I was just looking at this library which might do what you want. http://defiantjs.com/ You'd just have to write the xpath for that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex? No. Stop right there.

What you could do is to flatten the data first, or serve it flat in the first place.

```
[{
 playerId: ...,
 ...
 presetId: ...,
},{
 playerId: ...,
 ...
 presetId: ...,
}]
```

Assuming preset ID is unique, you can easily use `array.filter` or `array.find`.

```
var players = flatData.filter(player => player.presetID === ID_TO_FIND);

// or

var player = flatData.find(player => player.presetID === ID_TO_FIND);
```

Comment: How would I go about flattening it?